# How to highlight an entire row if A1 has text

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

So I have this custom formula for conditional formatting in google sheets

`=(A2 <> "")`

I want to copy this rule to all the cells in a row. When I try to apply it to the whole row it doesn't work.

This happens:[image: only the cell next to the cell with text has its color changed]
only the cell next to the cell with text has its color changed

I want the whole row to change color if I have text in the A2 spot.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add $ `=($A2<>"")` it will lock the row reference and therefore mark the whole row green.

[image]

Comment: Glad it helped you, you did a really good try ;)!!! Good luck with your project! =)